how much Jewish DNA does one have to have, to be considered Jewish/decent?
I have Jewish DNA in my bloodline, How much of a percentage is needed to be considered Jewish and I was wondering if anyone knows how to find more information about this or who can I talk to find this information out?

"To be considered Jewish" is largely depends on the policy of the community you'd like to join. Humanistic denominations require very little, and Orthodox communities make no use of DNA tests altogether.

Jewish DNA means nothing, since one could have a Jewish father, which doesn't make one Jewish, or be a convert, which doesn't change one's genetics. Even if your genetic markers show direct matrilineal descent, I don't know if that works if your mother's mother's mother didn't pass down any information about it

Thank you very much, makes sense to me!
